# WPF change style (with trigger) programmatically

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, styles

I need to change the background of the selected item in a list view, programmatically.

The style currently looks like this (as default)

```
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/selection-large.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
```

I need to be able to change that background image of the selected item programmatically.

I have attempted to do this myself however i am not really sure how to go about it.
I did notice that the listview has a styles property but other than that i am completely stumped.

I am using VB.net

**Edit**

Would something like this work? and if so, what am i doing wrong? My listview is completely invisible with this code.

```
    Dim trigger As New Trigger()
    trigger.Property = ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty
    trigger.Value = True
    trigger.Setters.Add(New Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink))
    mylistview.Style.Triggers.Add(trigger)
    mylistview.ItemContainerStyle = Style
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally work it out..
All i had to do was make another style based on the first one and give them both different x:keys.. Then i was able to change styles like this.

```
mylistview.ItemContainerStyle = DirectCast(FindResource("XKeyName"), Style)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `IsSelected` property to some bool value in the ViewModel and toggle that.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Item ViewModel:

```
private bool _isSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set 
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

In WPF you don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code, instead you use DataBinding and manipulate your models / ViewModels' properties

As an aside, I recommend against using PNG or other bitmap based stuff for regular UI elements in WPF.

Instead of that you should create your UI using WPF elements which are vector-based and thus resolution independent.

Comment: I don't think i understand what you're telling me to do.

Comment: @Mattigins sorry for the C# instead of VB.Net, I can barely remember the VB.Net syntax. You need to read up on MVVM and why it's important in WPF before ever writing a single line of code.

Comment: I have added my attempt to the initial post, am i on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within the XAML, Try this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/selection-large.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: It changes the background of the ListViewItem when you select the item... is it what you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, no, i have already accomplished that with the code in the initial post.. what i need to do is change what the background image is via the code-behind.

Comment: Do you want to accomplish the same what xaml does(setting the style trigger), from your code behind?

Comment: I have already found an answer to my question, thanks for your help.